# How to make a Zip Backup in TFS Build Definition Before Pushing New Changes

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build, msbuild

Before using xcopy feature of TFS 2017 Build Definition to push new changes,I want to take a Zip backup what is there so that in case I need to rollback.I can simply use that.

How can i do that. Which task i need to add in Build Definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Utility: Archive Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=vsts) task to zip the files. Just set the correct root folder which you want to make a zip.

[image]